# Registration Form Not Showing Invalid Fields?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

I have a joomla 2.5 setup, however the validations do not work on the forms. For example, if the password fields are left blank on the Registration form, then it will still validate and submit the form? I have added the relevant .css to highlight the errors (.invalid and label.invalid) but it still wouldn't do anything?

Comment: Do you have problems validating the joomla registration form ? or is it a custom form ?

Comment: It's the standard registration form. Even without any overrides it behaves the same way. Tried it with the defualt templates too, can't figure out what it could be!

Comment: Any errors on joomla debug or firebug ?

Comment: @Shaz Nope, no errors either?

Comment: Turns out some of the required js files were not loading properly, which stopped the validations from occuring. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to make sure all the system .js files are loading correctly as the form validation relies on them.

Comment: You should specify the files that need to be loaded for people that find this through Google.

Comment: The standard mootools .js files. This should be enabled when joomla is installed anyway.